# Float Left <UL> list with float right text boxes that are set below the UL list instead of set adjacent

Tags: html, css

I am just trying to float an unordered list left, and a set of textboxes to the right so that they are adjacent to each other and have a uniform look within a div tag. The issue is that the text boxes are to the right ... but are positioned below the ul items

```
.PersonLI
{
   float: left;
   clear: both;
   width: 100px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.PersonBox
{
   float: right;
   clear: both;
   width: 99px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.FirstObj
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}    
<div class="FirstObj">
   <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li class="PersonLI">First Name:</li>
      <li class="PersonLI">Last Name:</li>
      <li class="PersonLI">Address:</li>
      <li class="PersonLI">City:</li>
      <li class="PersonLI">State:</li>
      <li class="PersonLI">Zip Code:</li>
   </ul>
   <input id="txtFname" type="text" value="" class="PersonBox"/>
   <input id="txtLname" type="text" value="" class="PersonBox"/>
   <input id="txtAddr" type="text" value="" class="PersonBox"/>
   <input id="txtCity" type="text" value="" class="PersonBox"/>
   <input id="txtState" type="text" value="" class="PersonBox"/>
   <input id="txtZip" type="text" value="" class="PersonBox"/>
</div>
```

Could it be that I need to NOT clear the float on the last list item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup is kind of weird. A semantic form adapting your styles would look like this:

```
.FirstObj ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.FirstObj li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  clear: both;
}

.FirstObj label {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.FirstObj input {
  float: right;
  width: 99px
}

<div class="FirstObj">
   <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="txtFname">First Name:</label>
        <input id="txtFname" type="text" value="" />
      </li><li>
        <label for="txtLname">Last Name:</label>
        <input id="txtLname" type="text" value="" />
      </li><li>
        <label for="txtAddr">Address:</label>
        <input id="txtAddr" type="text" value="" />
      </li><li>
        <label for="txtCity">City:</label>
        <input id="txtCity" type="text" value="" />
      </li><li>
        <label for="txtState">State:</label>
        <input id="txtState" type="text" value="" />
      </li><li>
        <label for="txtZip">Zip Code:</label>
        <input id="txtZip" type="text" value="" />
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

It's alway a good idea to use [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/label)s. Here's the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/Fmzbm/

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason why you are not using `<label>` tags for these fields?

To answer your CSS question, `clear:both` is not needed on either of the elements if you want them side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your markup:

HTML:

    
        
            
                `First Name:`

CSS:

`.FirstObj label { float:left; }
.FirstObj input { float:right; }`

The code hinting is jacked up, need to try some more formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/qnev2/

You may want to change the fixed width of the `li` CSS rule to suit your needs but also change the markup and use the more semantically correct `label` tag. This also avoids the `float` property which in my experience can lead to undesirable behaviour if the HTML is re-flowed.